# Is it possible to manipulate a random stream?

Tags: random-variables, random-walk, random, random-matrices, random-functions

I got two random streams of binary data $A$ and $B$.

During each step, I can choose to pull a byte from stream $A$ or stream $B$.
My goal is to reduce the chances of pulling a pattern* $P$.

Is there a way to do some "smart game" where you choose to pull from $A$ or from $B$ based on some logic to reduce the chances of pulling the pattern $P$ in comparison to pulling only from one of the streams?

---

- a pattern is a consecutive sequence of bytes

Comment: Can you choose any arbitrary byte from either of the sequences in each step?

Comment: @Aryaaaaan, during each step, you get one byte. It can be 0 or 1. Your only choice is from which stream to pull it.

Comment: Seems like I don't get something. If you add up these streams and choose one byte from that stream (call it as C) each time, what's its difference with your problem

Comment: During each step, you can choose to pull from one of the streams. You will get one byte from each step. Then we search for a pattern in the output of the steps. The streams are never added up.